# Is there a secure way to store a password across pages on the client side?

Tags: javascript, ajax, security, squarespace, web-storage

I have a form that via AJAX validates login credentials from an external php script and database. I am attempting to password protect pages of a Squarespace website.

I am wondering if there is a way to securely store some kind of token returned when the user logs in using the login form that can be checked on each page the user attempts to access and redirects them or allows the to stay on the page based on if they successfully logged in.

I have looked into using cookies, web storage/local storage, window.name and several other methods that other people have used but none actually seem secure and I am not able to use php.

Is there a secure way to do this?

Comment: [HTML5 local storage](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage) could do it.

Comment: Depends what you call "secure". localStorage and cookies are designed so that other websites can't access them, regardless of any encryption. They just aren't allowed by the browser. But if you also want encryption you'll have to do it yourself.

Comment: Encryption alone isn't the solution when you're dealing with login tokens. It also has to do with not allowing me to guess the value. What you store in the cookie/localStorage should be a cryptographically secure random number so that I can't easily guess the value of someone else's cookie. For example, if we're just encrypting the password, what if you and I have the same password? If I update the cookie to use your username, I might be able to login as you. That's why the value stored is also important, not just how it is encrypted. Most Session management systems use a token as the storage.

Comment: I had looked into local storage but it is not secure enough for my purposes, for example an XSS attack would be able to display what is stored. If the data I was storing was not confidential I would definitely consider using local storage or cookies but after a lot of research I have found it's not recommended to store information such as passwords in local storage or cookies.

Comment: There is no client-storage that would be "secure" by the definition above. If your javascript can get to it, so can malicious javascript injected into the page.

Comment: I don't know enough about the provisions and restrictions on a Squarespace website to answer, but if they allow server-side processing there should be some provision for a _Session_. That is the magic random token that you want that others mentioned.  Without server-side protection no scheme for storing the password locally and checking it within the page itself (javascript?) can be secure.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by secure, what is the security that you want to achieve. Cookies are the standard means of security login/session tokens on the client side. What is the issue you are seeing with cookies ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on what you mean by "Secure." By default, for example, PHP's built in Session feature will use either a query string or cookies. The same is true for ASP.NET's Session feature. These are used on millions of websites and I'd say it is secure. The question is, what are you storing in the cookie? If you set a cookie like "IsLoggedIn" with a value of 1, that's not secure. However, if you do like PHP/ASP.NET do and store some random string (ideally a cryptographically secure random string) which is validated server side to a list of logged in random strings, you're good.

But that begs the question, why aren't you just using PHP sessions to store this information? See http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php Then you'd store the IsLoggedIn in the session object which is stored server side, not client side, and you're secure.

Comment: I have experience using php sessions and would definitely use them if I could. My issue is that I am limited by Squarespace as it does not support php. I am only able to basically inject code into page headers or in code blocks.